# Update image for Menuitem in cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
MenuItem *pageMenuItem;
pageMenuItem = MenuItemImage::create(menuImgNm, menuImgNm,
                                     CC_CALLBACK_1(RootLayer::buttonAction, this));
```

I want to change image for this based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try in this way:

- Create menuImgNm with CCSprite
- Using : CCMenuItemSprite with it
- You can change image with texture like:

`CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"new_image_name"];
[menuImgNm setTexture: tex];`

Hope this help!